# Issue with complex query using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I have 7 summary tables one for each day of the week.
txn_summary_monday...txn_summary_tuesday and so on...

The table store transaction counts for each date (each monday, each tuesday ...and so on), location, user, resource etc.

here is a sample Domain for the table

```
class TxnSummFri {
    Long id 
    Transaction trans
    Users guser
    Resources gresource
    Integer txnCount
    Date currentdate 
    String accountid

    }
```

I need to get total counts by location in a date range...(so it will be sum of all individual table counts by location on each table and then again a sum on that count by location for all tables).

One more thing is I will have to do a left join instead of inner joins on the summary tables as I want all possible locations in the 7 tables in the final list. (some tables might be missing some locations).

How do I write the above query in hibernate... I have the summary tables as domain objects in my application.
The application is based on grails/groovy.

Here is what I have written until now... gettin counts by locations for each table now to sum over these by location..

```
def SummTblList  = ['TxnSummMon','TxnSummTue','TxnSummWed','TxnSummThu','TxnSummFri','TxnSummSat','TxnSummSun']
def res_row
def resourceInstance=Resources.get(Long.parseLong(res_id))
         SummTblList.each{
         res_row=it.createCriteria().get {   

            eq('resource',resourceInstance)
            between('date', new Date()-31, new Date())        

            projections {  
            sum('actioncount')
            groupProperty 'location'         
                }                  
            }
```

**Something about out schema requirement(not related to above):**
Basically I have all kinds of queries on user transactions table... for aggregation on transactions, users, resources, by dates, by users, by resources, location. I do these queries for running charts using fusioncharts- a flash based tool, running reports using jasper reports and general UI search.

We were using a single table previously but to generate reports for users activity for last 7 days for 4 out of 4 resources it takes 60 seconds ...I want just make it minimum 20 times faster.

Thanks in advance,

Priyank

Comment: A table for each day of the week???  o_O

Comment: how would you seperate a super huge user_transactions table holding like 9 million records for faster access..any ideas for schema changes are also welcome..

Comment: Had you tried indexing any of the fields?  If so, which ones?  Do you have to query this data to select individual rows, or is it mostly used in aggregation?

Comment: yeah we tried indexing but its slow..

Comment: Hmm, that is a LOT of records.  I haven't dealt with a database with that many, MySQL or otherwise.  I'll see if I can think of anything else that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the database to have a single transaction table instead of tables for each day of the week.  This would greatly simplify the query.

If I did not have the ability to change the database, I would present a compelling argument to the database administrator as to why we should change the database to have a single transaction table.

If my compelling argument was denied, I would do something drastic (not necessarily in this order):

- see if you can create a view that somehow combines all the tables, and GORM map the view
- see if using advanced GORM/Hibernate features such as a base class would allow you to simplify your query
- break down and try to create a HQL query to select these values from each table
- if creating a HQL query causes problems, see if a native query would be simpler
- cry

Comment: On a serious note.. suppose no. of records in the table is 40-50 million, it definitely would be too huge for just one table to query on.. what approach of dividing the data would be best according to you..by the way we are frequently using last 1 month of data in our application than other data